# Animating WPF Expander with XamlFlair

Tags: wpf, xaml, animation, expander

I cannot figure out how to animate WPF Expander with XamlFlair. My simplest template (should expand from top to bottom and contract to top):

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Expander}">
    <DockPanel>
        <!-- EXPANDER HEADER -->
        <ToggleButton x:Name="ExpanderButton"
                        DockPanel.Dock="Top"
                        HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                        IsChecked="{Binding IsExpanded, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                        Content="Expand me"/>
        <!-- EXPANDER CONTENT -->
        <ContentPresenter x:Name="ExpanderContent"
                            DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"
                            xf:Animations.CombinedBinding="{Binding IsExpanded, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                            xf:Animations.Primary="{xf:Animate BasedOn={StaticResource ScaleFromTop}, Event=None, TransformOn=Layout}"
                            xf:Animations.Secondary="{xf:Animate BasedOn={StaticResource ScaleToTop}, Event=None, TransformOn=Layout}"
                            xf:Animations.StartWith="{StaticResource ScaleToTop}">
        </ContentPresenter>
    </DockPanel>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Problem is that no matter what initial `IsExpanded` property value is, Expander renders expanded at the beginning. When I add `xf:Animations.StartWith="{StaticResource ScaleToTop}"` (or `ScaleFromTop` - no mater which one) not only this does not fix the issue but also Expander's content is always blank.

Does anyone know how to make it work as expected? Thank you.

Comment: XamlFlair is my library. Let me know if you have solved the issue. If you have any other problems, feel free to ask in the Issues section on the XamlFlair GitHub.

Comment: Hi @Maximus. Yes, thank you. I have solved the issue by setting ScaleY="0". Answer below. It would be really nice if Expander content would slide from under the header like a drawer, but I’m not sure how to approach this. Scaling is good enough for me for now. Great library! Thanks!

Comment: Great to hear!  Try to use ClipToBounds="True"

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.uielement.cliptobounds?view=net-5.0

Answer (score 1):

I was scratching my head for two days, figured out the solution 5 minutes after posting the question.

Did not use `xf:Animations.StartWith`, added this instead:

```
<ContentPresenter.LayoutTransform>
    <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="0" />
</ContentPresenter.LayoutTransform>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to animate the expansion and contraction, you can write it in the Trigger.

```
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsExpanded" Value="True">
        <Setter TargetName="ExpandSite" Property="xf:Animations.CombinedBinding" Value="True" />
        <Setter TargetName="ExpandSite" Property="xf:Animations.Primary" Value="{xf:Animate BasedOn={StaticResource ScaleFromTop}, Event=None, Duration=300, TransformOn=Layout}" />
        <Setter TargetName="ExpandSite" Property="xf:Animations.Secondary" Value="{xf:Animate BasedOn={StaticResource ScaleToTop}, Event=None, Duration=300, TransformOn=Layout}" />
    </Trigger>
    <Trigger Property="IsExpanded" Value="False">
        <Setter TargetName="ExpandSite" Property="xf:Animations.CombinedBinding" Value="False" />
        <Setter TargetName="ExpandSite" Property="xf:Animations.Primary" Value="{xf:Animate BasedOn={StaticResource ScaleFromBottom}, Event=None, Duration=300, TransformOn=Layout}" />
        <Setter TargetName="ExpandSite" Property="xf:Animations.Secondary" Value="{xf:Animate BasedOn={StaticResource ScaleToBottom}, Event=None, Duration=300, TransformOn=Layout}" />
    </Trigger>
</ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```